# Reporting things for moderator attention

Tags: support

I would like to flag for moderator attention an ad hominem attack against me by one user on academia.stackexchange.com.  I have no way to flag things for moderator attention because I was suspended for a week, and I suspect (but it's only a suspicion) the suspension resulted in part from a complaint about the user whom I want to complain about.

Is there any way to contact the anonymous moderators?  They are identified only by user name.

Comment: You could contact Stack Exchange if it's serious... click the 'contact us' link at the bottom

Answer (score 14):

Outside of being able to flag...

You can reply to the message you got along with your suspension to discuss what happened.

If that doesn't work out to your satisfaction, drop us (Stack Exchange employees) a line via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page on the site.

Comment: You're mistaken: I cannot reply.  After exchange of a few messages that way, I get something saying I can't reply further (on a different topic: my complaint about an ad hominem attack).

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeah, further replies would require a moderator to respond. Sounds like it's time to contact us, then.

Comment: Who do you mean by "us"?

Comment: @MichaelHardy The SE team. Employees. The last paragraph in my answer. We can review what happened independently.

Comment: Stack Exchange employees! :)

Comment: Suppose A and B have a dispute, and A is more inclined to complain to B rather than about B to the moderators, and B is more inclined to go straight to the moderators. A tells B "Your behavior was wrong because etc.etc.etc." That statement from A to B becomes the subject of B's complaint to the moderators: "By telling me my behavior is wrong because etc.etc.etc., A is 'stalking' and 'harrassing' me." A is then suspended for "stalking" and "harrassing" and cannot write to the moderators. The moderators do not inform A of who it was that complained, so A can only guess. That's how it works.

Comment: @Michael I... okay. That could happen. This "A vs B in comments on another site" stuff isn't likely to accomplish much. I'm not sure what you want me to say here. Again, if you want a review, write to us. Include details. Whatever you write to employees via "contact us" is private, so don't feel obligated to be vague... Specificity helps.

Comment: I've now written two items to the employees.  The first time I clicked on "contact us" I found myself looking at a web interface, which I used to write my comments.  The second time, I was simply given an email address.  I don't know why it functioned differently the second time.

Comment: @Michael Were you on stackexchange.com the second time? Either way, the messages go to team@stackexchange.com, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear : The second time, I tried it both while logged in an while not logged in, with the same result both times.

Comment: I have now written to stackexchange employees a third time. This time it was to ask them to forward to the moderators of academia.stackexchange.com my complaint about a particular user stalking and harrassing me.  I would have reported it to the moderators myself if there were some way for me to do that.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Would love to have your thoughts on this if possible. Thank you. http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9584/why-does-this-off-topic-member-have-higher-rep-than-me-how-can-i-report-flag-t